# Scatterplot with categorical columns

Tags: python

I want to create a scatterplot so that x axis is value of variable `a`, and y axis is value of variable `b`, with hue being country.

[image: dataframe]

I have tried rearranging the data with multiindex and plotting with `sns.lmplot`, but it hasn't worked out.

What's the easiest way?

Comment: Welcome to SO. According to [ask] and [mcve], please think about the impression of your post to others who don't have a single idea of what you're dealing with these days. So please 1. No screenshots of code or data, post them as text, indented with 4 spaces or by Ctrl+k. 2. Tell us what you tried so far. 3. Tell us _what_ was going wrong 4. Tell us why that's not what you wanted, i.e.: tell us your expected result. Thank you for investing a little effort in a question while expecting effort of others when answering.

Answer (score 0):

Base on your information without any sample code.
I guess...

```py
sns.scatterplot(
    x=df[df['variable'] == 'a']['values'].values,
    y=df[df['variable'] == 'b']['values'].values
)
```